# iPhone: UILabel applying CGAffineTransformMakeRotation causing mysterious crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel

In

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil parentController:(GameViewController *)myGameController{
```

Have a series of transforming labels like so:

```
    deg90 = 1.570796326794897;
//....transforms
    background.center = CGPointMake(160,230);
    background.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg90);

    BetLabel.text = @"test";       
    BetLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg90);
```

That last line is crashing me with:

```
2010-04-13 21:04:47.858 Game[1204:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'
2010-04-13 21:04:47.893 Game[1204:207] Stack: (
    864992541,
    859229716, (lots of numbers)
```

But if I comment it out, I get the text changing fine.

**Update:** Uh oh, just did a test.. turns out the other transforms were on UIImageViews. Apparently rotating a label in this xib is causing the crash.

But in another file the transforms are working fine:

```
    newprofileentry.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.570796326794897);
    playerb0.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.570796326794897);
    playerb1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.570796326794897);
```

Tried substituting `deg90` with the full float value, still the same crash.

Tried cleaning cache, restarting IB and Xcode, cleaning all targets. Program has been running fine until I just added these labels. Tried deleting the label, readding and reconnecting the Outlet, too.

Thanks for reading, hope someone has an idea about this.

Cheers!

Comment: Your error message means that the error is somewhere in array's managing - there are an array with one element, and you are trying to use the second element (with index 1).
That's why I think that you search an error in wrong place. Maybe, you have some arrays in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do. I also have been adding the labels to the view as subviews - but why would .transform affect this? The labels aren't in any array except for the subview. Tried putting this code before I initialize the arrays, still crashing. Don't have any arrays with just 0 or 1 size.. seems to be a problem with the UILabel itself!

Comment: Have you tried making the @"Test" a [NSString stringWithString:@"Test"]?  There may be some weird thing going on where the static string is getting a some invalid initialization of the label/Transform.  By creating a new string (outside of the weird initialization done for @"Test"), this might make a difference in how the UIView handles the transform.  I know.  A bit out there but it is easy to try.

Comment: Please use `M_PI/2` instead of `1.570796326794897`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest moving the transforms out of `initWithNib:` It's possible that the you're trying to modify something that doesn't yet exist because the objects in the nib are still initializing.

You should also examine the nib file (in Interface Builder or with ibtool) to see if there is something scrambled with that particular label. To test that, you could swap out its order in the initialization with another label to see if the problem is with that particular label or whether it is with any label or object in the last position.

Posting more code in context would probably help.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.
Bizzarely, putting
 newt = [[gametoken alloc] init];
 [gametokens2 addObject:newt];
 [newt release];

instead of inside of a for loop did the trick. Not sure why.. but it works now. Was crashing on accessing index 1 of that object. Don't know why the label would related to that. Strange memory error?